# Simple show/hide elements binding to local variables

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, styled-components

How would one show/hide elements based on a local Boolean variable with `styled-components`?

I have the following:

```
export const Test = styled.div`
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: pink;
`;

let visible = true;

function toggle() {
    visible = !visible;
}
```

```
export function App() {
    return(
        <button onClick={toggle}>toggle</button>
        <Info show={visible}>Some info</Info>
    );
}
```

```
import App from './App';

ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[**Here is a stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/styled-components-example-h3aymq)

Comment: can you add  a working example here? https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @Radu added an example

Comment: as @pkyo suggested look into class based components, it will be way easier for you to pass props like that, if  not I suggest you look into conditional rendering in react (https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) that is if you are not required to do it with `styled-components`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

improved complete code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

class App extends Component {
  state={toggle:true}
   // Functions
    toggleIt=()=> {
      this.setState(prev=>({toggle:!prev.toggle}))
    } 
  render() {
    const Test = styled.div`
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: pink;
    display: ${props => props.show ? 'block' : 'none'}
`;

    return (
      // html
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleIt}>Toggle me</button>
        <Test show={this.state.toggle}>Some info</Test>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default styled(App) `
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
`;
```

for your reference
[Live Demo](https://styled-components-example-axa674.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to introduce state in your component in which case you will have to use a class component instead of a function component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export const Test = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
    display: props.size ? 'block' : 'none'
}))`
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: pink;
`;

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            visible: true
        }
    }
    toggle() {
        this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible })
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <button onClick={this.toggle}>toggle</button>
            <Info show={this.state.visible}>Some info</Info>
        );
    }
}
```

[Function and class components React Docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

Comment: When I used the React CLI to start a new app, it didn't give me code in the format though... It's been a while since I've used React. Could it be that they have set it out differently now? Would you be able to make these adjustments easily to the attached stackblitz?